# Autodesk viewer - Lack of data with local svf file

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I have the following problem with the Autodesk API - viewer.

When I read a file with an urn, I can get data such as refPointTransform.

But when I load a local svf file, I can't.

Here is a photo with an urn:
[image]

As you can see, there is refPointTransform.

And a photo of a local svf file.

[image]

And there is no refPointTransform.

Do you know why? Have I done something wrong?

Comment: I tried with a simple Revit file. it looks it does not contain refPointTransform, either urn on-line or local svf. I am further checking. May I know which file type you are testing with?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have try with the translation in SVF of a revit file.

Comment: I tested with another Revit sample file rac_advanced_sample_project.rvt. It has refPointTransform in both urn on-line or local svf. So it sounds there is some other special scenarios (or maybe issues) that only urn on-line has the property. I am checking with our engineer team. In the same time, could you also share your Revit file? probably we will need to diagnose it. please email me directly xiaodong.liang@autodesk.com you do not want to share the model in public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happy new year! I got the comments from engineer team:  If the user never modifies the "Site Location" in the Revit model, it does not export such a property. Only after the user has specified the "Site Location" in the Revit model (through "Location Weather and Site" dialog in Revit), would this property be exported. And since 2018, user can do this by importing a geo-referenced DWG/RVT as a link and then acquire the location from the link.

As mentioned in my comments at the beginning, I can only find the model with/without such property (both with on-line urn or offline SVF). I did not see a model that has such property with on-line urn, but not with offline SVF. Could you send me a test file at xiaodong.liang@autodesk.com? Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, I will send you my files! Sorry for having not respond before.

Comment: I have sent you a message

Comment: @Wandrille, sorry, i seemed not to get an email from you, including junk box. could you send it again? please also cc to forge.help@autodesk.com in case something is problematic between my email and yours. thank you.

Comment: I have sent you the email again with forge.help in cc.
Thanks for you concern! I appreciate it very much.